# Move View Controller main view (self.view) subviews to scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

1. I am having view controller with subviews & applied constraints.
2. Problem: What i am trying to do is to add scrollview programmatically for
   only iPhone 4s device with all subviews of self.view in scrollview.
3. The scrollview should contain all subviews of self.view (which i add using self.view.subviews).

   4. Codes i tried

   if DeviceType.IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS {

   ```
       //Add Scrollview to self.view
       let scrollview : UIScrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRectMake(0,0,320,480))
       scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true;
       scrollview.scrollEnabled = true;
       scrollview.userInteractionEnabled = true;

      // scrollview.addSubview(self.view) /

       let total : NSArray = (self.view.subviews as NSArray).copy() as! NSArray

       //Add elements to scrollview but subviewes don't get scroll
       for subview in total
       {
           scrollview.addSubview(subview as! UIView)
       }
       /// Results in blank white screen. Reason: May be scrollview & self.view pointing to same objects
       for subview in self.view.subviews {

           subview.removeFromSuperview()
       }

      self.view.addSubview(scrollview)

       scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height+200)

       }
   ```
4. I am  aware of Size class & give problem can be resolved.
5. I am also aware that adding scrollview in storyboard & hiding for all devices except iPhone 4s may work.

Comment: Why don't you just put all your subviews in a scroll view all the time and disable scrolling if you have enough space to display everything?

Comment: @Patrick, i hope you went through point no. 5. I know this is preferred but i am curious to know how can be done in other way (Stated in point no. 2 Problem)? Please go through question & try to understand the problem statements before negative marking.

Comment: I'm not the one who down voted you, I think this is a legitimate question. My comment was a helpful suggestion—and pardon me, I did not see point no. 5 on your list.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code more closely, I think I see a few problems that are causing your expectations to not be met.

```
let total : NSArray = (self.view.subviews as NSArray).copy() as! NSArray
```

This does not create a copy of each view in the `subviews` array, it only makes a copy of the array, the elements of which are the same as those pointed to by the source array.  To copy each element, you should do something like this:

```
let total = self.view.subviews.map { $0.copy() }
```

In your code when you add all of those views to a new superview, they are automatically removed from the previous superview.  So now in the loop where you are calling `subview.removeFromSuperview()` on each element, you are removing each element from the new superview to which you just added them, which makes sense that you would end up with a blank white screen.

So, if it were me, I would not make copies of all the subviews and then just add each one to a new superview, knowing that they will be removed from their previous superview.  Then you don't have to iterate through and remove the old ones.

Comment: @Thanks Patrick for valuable inputs. No luck (Means view get appear with all element but only upper image view get scroll & rest of elements do not) even if i remove   subview.removeFromSuperview(). &  let total = self.view.subviews.map { $0.copy() } gets crash.